# How does Django manage different subdomains on one Django project?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I want my Django project to be accessible at many different endpoints. For one app, I want it accessible at `app.domain.com` and for another app I want it accessible at `dashboard.domain.com`. How can I achieve this? I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Route 53.

I tried looking at Django's [djangoproject.com](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and their [Github repo](https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com), as they do this. However, I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two `settings.py` file, with two associated `urls.py` files :

*app_settings.py*

```py
from my_project.settings import *

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.app_urls'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['app.domain.com']
```

*dashboard_settings.py*

```py
from my_project.settings import *

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_project.dashboard_urls'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['dashboard.domain.com']
```

Define your urls for each website respectively in `my_project/app_urls.py` and `my_project/dashboard_urls.py`

Then start two instances of your django project (with uwsgi, gunicorn ou whatever you use) with those two distinct settings files (using `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable for example).

This way, both instances shares the same codebase but exposes distinct urls.

For example, using uwsgi, you could have those two files (with distinct ports) :

*app.ini*

```
[uwsgi]
http = 127.0.0.1:8001
module = my_project.wsgi
processes = 4
threads = 2
pidfile = app.pid
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.app_settings
```

*dashboard.ini*

```
[uwsgi]
http = 127.0.0.1:8002
module = my_project.wsgi
processes = 4
threads = 2
pidfile = app.pid
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.dashboard_settings
```

Comment: I see, so I will need to have two instances running on Ec2? One of them linked with my route 53 subdomain of `app.domain.com` and another with my route 53 subdomain of `dashboard.domain.com`? Is it possible to have 2 separate django projects instead?

Comment: You can have 1 ec2 instance running both apps on distincts ports, and then use nginx to make the routing between domain and port. Or you can have 2 ec2 instances, with an app on each.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Do you know which one will be cheaper? Or which one is better practice/easier for the future?

Comment: I you takes 1 ec2 instance for each, each one are monitored independantly which can be great. With 2 app on 1 ec2 instance, it is cheaper and everything is centralized (and maybe more tweaky to deploy on Beanstalk)